# ALSA close PCM handle failed

Tags: audio, alsa, pcm

After captured audio, I use

```
snd_pcm_drain(phandle);
snd_pcm_close(phandle);
```

to close PCM
 But I got "double free or corruption(!pre):0x01694880 ***" error

Firstly, I use following function to initial the pcm handle;

```
static snd_pcm_t *handle;
int initExtAudio()
{
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    const char *card = "hw:0,0";

    snd_pcm_open(&handle, card, SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);

    snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
    return 0;
}
```

then, I use `snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, frames);` to read pcm data and save;

finally, I use uninit function to close pcm handle:

```
snd_pcm_drain(handle);
snd_pcm_close(handle);
```

init -> read -> uninit -> init -> read -> uninit, when uninit the second time, it comes to error:`double free or corruption(!pre):0x01694880 ***`, so how should I avoid this error? when the sound card was turned off, I should uninit the handle, when next time it is turned on I should init it again, right?

Comment: This is likely to be a bug somewhere in the rest of the program. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @CL.so I added my sample, thank you for reply.

Comment: Check all function calls for errors.